# Zooming stops working using highstock chart after updating jQuery,

Tags: jquery, zooming, highcharts

I am using highstock chart version v1.2.5 and highchart v2.3.5 with jQuery 1.5.1. I have to work with next version of jQuery 1.7.2. Mostly everything work correct instead of zooming. It is stopped to work.
It is zoomed by X axis.

```
zoomType: 'x',
```

Stack trace is next:

- Anonymous function [highstock.js] Line 572   Script
- Anonymous function [highcharts.js] Line 58   Script
- zoom [highstock.js] Line 572 Script
- Anonymous function [highstock.js] Line 480   Script
- fireEvent [highcharts.js] Line 62    Script
- a [highstock.js] Line 480    Script
- dispatch [jquery-1.7.2.min.js] Line 3    Script
- i [jquery-1.7.2.min.js] Line 3   Script

It is crashed in the next code: `if (b.tracker[e.isXAxis ? "zoomX" : "zoomY"])` tracker is undefined.

Does anybody meet this issue and know any solution for this?

Comment: Have you specific example? Please take look at example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/zoomtype-x/ which works well with jquery 1.7.2

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know when create this post that issue reproduced only when I have related graphs on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a number reasons for such kind of behavior:

- Highcharts are included in Highstock. So I only need to load the highstock.js file.
- I have implemented complex behavuior where zooming of one graph recreates other graphs. Looks like that there drag&drop calls some code that related to all graphs on page, and in some moment it calls not initialized graph. I have add some extra check for avoiding calls no initialized graphs.

This two steps solved my issue.